# How to disable DNS hijacking by my ISP in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, dns, search-engines

When I search for certain terms in the address bar of firefox, I get redirected to an extremely annoying "custom google search" page which has been foisted upon me by my ISP. I do not use google. I use duckduckgo. This is unacceptable.
Example, searching for "centrelink" in firefox redirects me to this page: [google.dodo.com.au/search.html?q=centrelink](http://google.dodo.com.au/search.html?q=centrelink)

I can work around this by wacking "dummy" search terms in the address bar alongside my main search, but I really should not have to do this. How can I force firefox to ignore my ISP and just run the search through duckduckgo like it usually would?

I note that Google chrome does not suffer from the same problem, so obviously this is something that can be fixed from my end and I do not have to contact my ISP. There simply has to be a setting somewhere in firefox which will disable this obnoxious behaviour. Where is it?

Comment: Did you try changing your default search provider on Firefox? https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/search-web-address-bar

Comment: Chnage your DNS provider and/or if it still happens use a VPN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no Firefox setting for that. It is done by your ISP's DNS servers, and the only way to "opt out" is to not use them.

The reason it doesn't affect Chrome is because it performs [*detection*](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/intranet_redirect_detector.cc?l=79) of NXDOMAIN hijacking, remembers what the redirect looks like, and purposefully [ignores](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/ui/omnibox/chrome_omnibox_navigation_observer.cc?type=cs&l=45) it later on.

As long as other browsers don't implement this detection, your only option is to use other DNS servers (e.g. Google Public DNS).

Comment: changing DNS server did the trick! cheers